# For a hyperbola's asymptote, why is the denominator of $y$ always above the denominator of $x$?

Tags: conic-sections

For example, $${x^2\over a^2} - {y^2\over b^2} = 1$$ would have an asymptote of $$\pm y = {{b\over a }x}$$

and $${y^2\over a^2} - {x^2\over b^2} = 1$$
would have an asymptote of $$\pm y = {{a\over b }x}$$

For both asymptotes, they follow the form of $$\pm y = {\sqrt{\text{denominator of } y\over \text{denominator of } x}x}$$

Why does the asymptotes always takes this form?

Comment: It might be helpful to look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptote), under the voice 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's review how do we find the asymptotes.

For the first case,

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

$$\frac{y^2}{b^2}=\frac{x^2}{a^2}-1$$

$$y^2=\frac{b^2x^2}{a^2}-b^2$$

When $x$ is very very huge in magnitude,

$$y^2 \approx \frac{b^2x^2}{a^2}$$

We are expressing $y^2$ as a function of of $x^2$, hence $b^2$ is brought up to the numerator.

Similarly for the other case.